# Как определить содержит ли массив элементов определенные слова

Tags: javascript

Есть массив обьектов:

```
const arr = [
{
label: 'Phone',
value: '',
},
{
label: 'Phone 1',
value: '',
},
{
label: 'email',
value: '',
}
]
```

Нужно проверить если value пустое и это label есть в массиве contacts = ['phone', 'email'] то value нужно присвоить No permission. Проблема с моим кодом что оно находит только Email, Phone а вот Phone 1 не находит а должно тоесть Phone 1 Тоже должно быть присвоено No permission.

```
arr.map((item) => {
   if (!item.value) {
        const contacts = ['phone', 'email'];
        const hasLabel = contacts.includes(item.label.toLowerCase());
        item.value = hasLabel ? 'No permission' : item.value;
    }

   return item;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = getObject();

const result = obj.map((item) => {
   if (!item.value) {
        const contacts = ['phone', 'email'];
        const hasLabel = contacts.some(el => item.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(el));
        item.value = hasLabel ? 'No permission' : item.value;
    }

   return item;
});

console.log(result);

function getObject() {
  return [{
      label: 'Phone',
      value: '',
    },
    {
      label: 'Phone 1',
      value: '',
    },
    {
      label: 'email',
      value: '',
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
     arr.map((item) => {
        if (!item.value) {
             const contacts = [/phone/i, /email/i];
             const hasLabel = contacts.some(v=>v.test(item.label));
             item.value = hasLabel ? 'No permission' : item.value;
         }

         return item;
     });
```